# Update DataTable cell's display value but retain original data source

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Is there anyway that allows us to update a cell(s) display value while not change the underlying source data?

If we were to update a cell value via DataTable API e.g. `cell().data('new_value')`:-

- can change the cell's display value
- any renderer registered at column definition works as intended
- can search/filter works as expected
- BUT the original data source/value is lost

If we were to update a cell value via DOM function e.g. `cell().html('new_value')`:-

- change the cell's display value
- registered renderer not working
- new_value cannot be find when searching
- the original data source/value is untouched

Is there anyway that allows us to update a cell(s) display value while not change the underlying source data?

Comment: There are many ways to do that, u can f.e. save new data to a tmp table or an object and build a new datatable from this source.

Comment: @toffler my intention is, to update the DataTable displayed to user. Sorting & filtering should reflect with the new data. But user should have the ability to 'reset' per row. Not the whole table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going thru DataTables API shows nothing than can achieve my use case. However, i found another solution to achieve my intention.

I store the original data in `<tr>` HTML5 data attributes as part of `rowCreated` callbacks.

I just hope that the should be a way to reset the table by cell, instead of the whole table via `.destroy()`